# TimeSpan formatting to minutes ans seconds without hours

Tags: c#, formatting, timespan

I need format TimeSpan to minutes and seconds(without hours), I looks to MSDN formatting but not found any example which I can reuse.

Example of what I need:

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) --> 00:01
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) --> 01:00
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600) --> 60:00
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(36000) --> 600:00
```

Any ideas which format possible use to convert TimeSpan to string in minutes:seconds format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3123);

var result = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}", (int) timeSpan.TotalMinutes, timeSpan.Seconds);

// result = "52:03"
```

Comment: As I make sense it is not possible done via TimeSpan.ToString(format)?

Comment: Which .NET Version are you using? TimeSpan.ToString(format) only takes custom format string in .NET4+

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the first part and also pad the number of seconds with a custom format string:

```
var formatted = string.Format("{0}:{1:D2}", (int)ts.TotalMinutes, ts.Seconds);
```

Comment: For 90 seconds --> 1.5:30

Comment: @Толя: Ah yes, I forgot. Added a cast to `int` to get rid of the fraction.

Answer (score 1):

For those who prefer to just pass string format

```
timespan.ToString("mm\\:ss");
```

Comment: The problem with this is that "mm" ranges from "00" to "59". So you need to use TotalMinutes as suggested by other answers if the TimeSpan ever goes beyond 1 hour.